# Custom component does not display values from assignTo attribute

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="opportunity" >
<c:vendortab componentValue="{!Opportunity.AccountId}"/>
</apex:page>
```

VF Component:

```
<apex:component controller="componenttester" access="global">
<apex:attribute name="componentValue" description="testing" type="Id" required="required" assignTo="{!acct}"/>
<apex:form >
<apex:tabPanel id="theTabPanel" >
<apex:tab label="Contactdetails" name="Contactdetails" id="Contactdetails">
<apex:pageBlock title="Account Detail">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Contacts" columns="1">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conts}" var="cont" rows="10">
<apex:column value="{!cont.Id}"/>
<apex:column value="{!cont.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!cont.Email}"/>
<apex:column value="{!cont.Phone}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

apex class:

```
public class componenttester 
{
public List<Contact> conts {get; set;}
public Id acct {get; set;}
public componenttester(){
}
public void componenttest() 
{
system.debug(acct);
conts=[select id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact where AccountId=:acct];
system.debug(conts);
}
}
```

I have added the vf page as section in the opportunity layout. i am passing the accountid from opportunity and query the contact corresponding to the account and displaying the list of contact in the standard opportunity layout as inline vf section.but i am not get any contact values.kindly help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that you aren't adhering to the [VF page order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_get_request.htm).

Specifically #2 and #3 below:

> 1. The constructor methods on the associated custom controller or
>      controller extension classes are called, instantiating the controller
>      objects.
> 2. If the page contains any custom components, they are created
>      and the constructor methods on any associated custom controllers or
>      controller extensions are executed. If attributes are set on the
>      custom component using expressions, the expressions are evaluated
>      after the constructors are evaluated.
> 3. The page then executes any
>      assignTo attributes on any custom components on the page. After the
>      assignTo methods are executed, expressions are evaluated, the action
>      attribute on the  component is evaluated, and all other
>      method calls, such as getting or setting a property value, are made.
> 4. If the page contains an  component, all of the information
>      necessary to maintain the state of the database between page requests
>      is saved as an encrypted view state. The view state is updated
>      whenever the page is updated.
> 5. The resulting HTML is sent to the
>      browser.  If there are any client-side technologies on the page, such
>      as JavaScript, the browser executes them.

The attribute `componentValue` is assigned to the custom component controller property `acct` after the constructor is evaluated.

Hence, @VamsiKrishna is correct in his second comment - you need to do this:

```
public List<Contact> conts {
   get {return [select id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact where AccountId=:acct] ;
   }
   set;
}
```

and the constructor should be:

```
public void componenttest() {}
```

There are lots of good reasons why VF controller constructors should be as simple as possible and data fetched using [idempotent properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/01/implementing-idempotent-operations-with-salesforce.html)

As an aside, variable `acct` should more be more properly named `acctId` as it is of type ID and `acct` normally implies an Sobject.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the contacts SOQL in a method which is never getting called. you should either move the SOQL inside the constructor of the controller class or in the set accessor if the acc property..

change this

```
public void componenttest() 
{
system.debug(acct);
conts=[select id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact where AccountId=:acct];
system.debug(conts);
}
```

to

```
public componenttester() 
{
system.debug(acct);
conts=[select id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact where AccountId=:acct];
system.debug(conts);
}
```

or

```
public Id acct 
{
   get; 
   set{ conts=[select id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact where AccountId=:acct]; }
}
```

Comment: if i move the soql inside constructor acct doesnot have value.it is becoming null

Comment: try moving it in the property set accessor